# SharePoint 2016 Search API Query

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-search, search-query

Just wondering if someone can help me with SharePoint 2016 Search query, basically I am trying to query special field values in SharePoint List.

Search Query:

```
http://XXXXXX/_api/search/query?refinementfilters=FIELDNAME:"123"'&path='http://XXXXXXXX/sites/XXXXXXX/ProductsRepository'
```

Comment: Are you trying to build the REST query or the search query for Search results webpart? Can you please tell us the exact issue you are facing using the mentioned query?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I had an issue with multiple refinement filters, when I tried to execute SharePoint Search query, but the issue is resolved now. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper query query which solved my issue:

```
https://site/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&rowlimit=10&selectproperties='Path,Title,LastModifiedTime'&refinementfilters='and(Path:("http://site/sites/sitecollection/Lists/listname"),FieldName:equals("20521368"))'
```